# Python for iOS as a static library

Tags: python, ios

Is there a static Python library I can link with my XCode projects to embedd a Python interpreter? Where can I find it (pre build)? I know that there are some projects, claiming to generate such a static lib (like kivy, embedded-python, ignifuga), but all of these builds fail for some reasons or another (eg version conflict of tools)and I don't want spend days getting this to work.

Comment: just crosscompile Python from source...it's not that hard since it has very few dependencies.

Comment: Maybe my English was too bad bad, but there is a simple (and real) question: Where (URL) can I find a ready to link library to embed Python into an iOS project?

Comment: Probably doesn't exist. Like I said, build it yourself from source. It really isn't nearly that hard (build for your own machine first just to try the build system, then cross build by following any of the Cross Compile Python instructions on the Internet).

Comment: @nneoneo: It is not that easy, as eg even Python for iOS (sold in the AppStore but a great product otherwise) gets 2**100 wrong.

Comment: That would greatly surprise me. The `long` implementation in Python should be totally platform-independent...

Comment: I now found a different solution: Just bought Pythonista in the AppStore and used its export to XCode feature, which created a complete XCOde project from Python files.

Comment: i tried this. unfortunately the resulting xcode project hides the phython invocation code in a precompiled lib.